# How to grab contents based on text in previous HTML class

Tags: xpath

```
<h4 class="popup-title"><a href="/united-states/los-angeles">Cafe in Los Angeles</a></h4>
                      <div class="popup-image"><a href="/united-states/los-angeles"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/190x125/public/city/photos/los-angeles.jpg"/></a></div>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/united-states/los-angeles">Find out more</a>
        </div>
      </info-window>

      <marker-label position="[34.061,-118.444]"
```

I am trying to use xpath to grab coordinates in `marker-label position`

Based on the text `Cafe in Los Angeles`

I am trying variations of: `//h4/a[contains(., 'Cafe in Los Angeles')]/parent::marker-label/@position`
But don't seem to be having much luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct xpath.

```
//a[normalize-space(.)='Cafe in Los Angeles']/parent::h4/following-sibling::marker-label/@position
```

You can also do this.

```
//h4[//a[normalize-pace(.)='Cafe in Los Angeles')]]/following-sibling::marker-label/@position
```